# Can entity framework 6.1 work with object type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

i would like to find out how can i work with object type with entity framework 6.1 (code first, migration).

lets say i have 3 objects: Page, Article and Blog.

i would like to have in the database one main table: page.

Article and Blog tables will contain only an id to page table.

When i have a list of pages i should be able to check the type of each object - some will be Article and some will be Blogs.

When i save an article object into the database, it should be saved on the page table with the Article type in the database (page record with article record and ids between them).

any advice will be propitiated

Thank you

Ori

Comment: What is your concrete problem? How is your mapping right now?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, With this example i didnt add any mapping. in the dbContext i have only DbSet<Page>, DbSet<Article>.

Comment: What you need is called Table-per-Hierarchy. A tutorial: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

Comment: You should start by researching on your own and using the plenty available documentation. When you have a specific issue, that's when SO comes into play.